# Use Chrome Apps with Brave?

Tags: brave, chrome-app

I've used Google Chrome for many years, but recently I decided to get off the Google train entirely. To replace Chrome, I decided to use Brave, which made the transition very easy because I can easily import many of the settings (bookmarks and passwords) from Chrome to Brave. Something that amazed me when I found out about it, is that you can use the Chrome Web Store, with Brave, to download extensions... and they will all work with Brave! Well, almost all.

My issue now is that of the extensions I used in Google Chrome, one was [Web Server for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb), which is actually classified as a "Chrome App". Out of all the "extensions", this one is the only that I couldn't get to work. I can click on the icon all I want, but the app just won't start.

Is there a setting I'm missing? Or do "apps" not work in Brave like they do in Google Chrome?

Comment: Brave is chromium-based, not Chrome. The two are similar but not the same.

Comment: @Tetsujin The Chromium Blog has mentioned several times Chrome Apps, like this post from [Introducing the new Chrome Apps Developer Tool](https://blog.chromium.org/2013/11/introducing-new-chrome-apps-developer.html) 2013 so I think that it's fair to ask if chromium based browsers are able to do things with them. Unfortunatelly they are being retired. See my [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1769310/152004)

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays Chrome Apps only works in Chromebooks / Chrome OS until at least 2025.

---

From [Add & open Chrome apps](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/3060053?hl=en)

> On your Chromebook, you can add and open apps from the Chrome Web Store.
>
> Important: Chrome Apps in the Chrome Web Store are only supported on Chromebooks and won't work on Windows, Mac, or Linux after December 2022. You can still use the Extensions and Themes that are available in the Chrome Web Store.

From [Extending Chrome App Support on Chrome OS](https://blog.chromium.org/2021/10/extending-chrome-app-support-on-chrome.html)

> Today we're announcing an important update to the previously communicated Chrome app support timeline. Based on feedback from our Enterprise and Education customers and partners, we have made the decision to extend Chrome app support for those users on Chrome OS until at least January 2025.

Resources

- [Moving Forward from Chrome Apps](https://blog.chromium.org/2020/01/moving-forward-from-chrome-apps.html)
- [Changes to the Chrome App Support Timeline](https://blog.chromium.org/2020/08/changes-to-chrome-app-support-timeline.html)